# Polynomial factoring over finite fields

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, algorithms, computational-complexity, finite-fields

What is known in general about the complexity of factoring polynomials over finite fields?

For instance given $\Bbb F_q$ where $q=p^n$ and total degree $d$ polynomial in $m$ variables what can we say about the complexity of factoring polynomials over $\Bbb F_q[x_1,\dots,x_m]$? In general is there a class of polynomials whose factoring is $NP$-hard or $coNP$-hard?

Is there a good reference to understand the topic well?

Comment: The Cantor-Zassenhaus algorithm is commonly used. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm

Comment: For complexity of the C-Z algorithm see Theorem 5 on page 20 of http://digitalcommons.uconn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1380&context=srhonors_theses for its complexity (and perhaps Chapter 6 of http://www.amazon.com/Algebraic-Coding-Theory-Revised-Edition/dp/9814635898 gives further information).

Comment: The above are for 1-variable polynomials over finite fields.  For $m>1$ variables is it comparable in difficulty to factoring polynomials in $m-1$ variables over $\mathbf{Z}$?

Comment: @nfdc23 Good problem do not know.

Answer (score 8):

For dense univariate polynomials, the state of the art is due to Kedlaya and Umans ([Fast polynomial factorization and modular composition](http://dx.doi.org/10.1137/08073408X), *SIAM J. Comput.* **40** (2011), 1767–1802).  They obtain randomized algorithms for factoring degree $n$ univariate polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_q$ requiring $O(n^{1.5 + o(1)}\,{\rm log}^{1+o(1)} q+ n^{1 + o(1)}\,{\rm log}^{2+o(1)} q)$ bit operations.

The multivariate case admits a polynomial time reduction to the univariate case.  For a good discussion of this and related topics (such as factoring sparse polynomials), see Kaltofen's survey, [Polynomial factorization 1987–1991](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~kaltofen/bibliography/92/Ka92_latin.pdf), in Proc. Latin '92, Springer LNCS 583 (1992), 294–313.

I believe that it is still open whether there is a *deterministic* polynomial time factoring algorithm, although some partial results are known assuming the extended Riemann hypothesis.